# Would I use a tree in order to store all Holidays in each month?

Tags: data-structures

I'm currently working on a java program that shows a calendar for 2019. https://github.com/zhadjah9559/Side_Proj_Calendar

I want the holidays to show up on the right-hand side in the scroll pane. I first need a data struct in order to store all the holidays.  Would a binary tree be the best data structure to implement this function?

Comment: Why not just a list?

Comment: "be the best data structure" --- there is nothing absolutely "the best" anything for a problem. It either fits your functional and non-functional requirements or not.

Comment: Map seems to be the best option. Binary Tree is certainly an overkill here. There isn't a relationship between holidays to justify it

Comment: sinanspd   Only reason why I was thinking tree is because some holidays have the same month. That way the program would display all holidays in that month not just christmas. IE:    ```December-> Days of Hannukah ^ Christmas ^ News Years Eve```

Answer (score 1):

how about a map where keys are month, values are lists of holidays

```py
{
    JAN :  [New Years, Milk day, ...]
    ...
    DEC :  [Christmas, Kwanzaa, ...]
}
```